# Using renderScene but navigation is not working

Tags: navigation, react-native, tabview

I'm trying to use Tabview to stick head to the top in react native

However, when I enter into the page, I have a problem with navigation.

when it has just one case, the navigation works properly, like goBack and goPage.

when i have more than two tabs, it just exit from the app.

is there any solution that I can use more than 2 tabs and proper navigation?

Here is my code.

```
const renderScene = ({route}) => {
    switch (route.key) {
        case 'tab1':
          return (
            <MenuScreen storeSeq={storeSeq} parent={prop.parent} naviRef={prop.naviRef}/>
        );
        case 'tab2':
          return (
            <InfoScreen storeSeq={storeSeq} parent={prop.parent} naviRef={prop.naviRef}/>
        );
        case 'tab3':
          return (
            <ReviewScreen storeSeq={storeSeq} parent={prop.parent} naviRef={prop.naviRef}/>
        );
      default:
        return null;
    }
    
  };
```

This is the TabView scene.js

```
 render() {
    return (
      <CustomTabView
        storeSeq={storeSeq}
        parent={this}
        naviRef={this.props.navigation}
      />
    );
  }
```

This is the App.js where calls the tabview

Comment: As I am making a project, I couldn't post entire code for security problem... I apologize that I can't post further more details..

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has the trouble which navigation does not work when you are using renderscene,
check your tab screen or other components whether it has Webview in it. Webview and tab navigator collapsed and make out error. I just realized that if i erase webview, navigation works smoothly. I have to get solution to show out the map in other way..